# Using Drop Down List to modify a GridView in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, dropdownlistfor

Here's my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


}
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    connection db_obj1 = new connection();
    SqlConnection sql_obj = db_obj1.Connect();
    if (this.DropDownList1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    {
        string brand = DropDownList1.Items[DropDownList1.SelectedIndex].ToString();

        string query = "Select Product,Model, NetPrice, Cost, Profit from products where Brand='" + brand + "'";

        // SqlDataReader query_read = query.ExecuteReader();

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, sql_obj);
        //    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tab",);
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        adapter.Fill(table);
        //  Response.Write(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());

        GridView grd = new GridView();
        grd.FindControl("GridView1");


        grd.DataSource = table;
        grd.DataBind();


    }


}
```

The problem is that when I run the code, I only see the drop down list and no GridView even when I select dofferent options. I tried debugging and it seems that the table DOES get filled and the only problem that I think is in the line 'grd.FindControl("GridView1").Is this the proper way to give a gridview a data source?

Comment: And I don't understand why I can't access 'GridView1' directly here. That would easily solve my problem

Comment: Can't you use a blend of jquery and ajax?

Comment: is the dropdown in the gridview ?

Comment: what are you doing with the object of the gridview `grd`.

Comment: Post your markup. Looks like you forgot to add gridview.

Answer (score 0):

According to me you should not use like

```
string brand = DropDownList1.Items[DropDownList1.SelectedIndex].ToString();
```

on behalf that try as below

```
string brand = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
```

after that fire a query.
i hope it will halpful.

**After Edit** now use this code

```
    string query = "Select Product,Model, NetPrice, Cost, Profit from products where Brand='" + brand + "'";


    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, sql_obj);
    //    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tab",);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable table;
    adapter.SelectCommand = command;
    adapter.Fill(ds, "ABC");
    table = ds.Tables["ABC"];
    //  Response.Write(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());

    GridView grd = new GridView();
    grd.FindControl("GridView1");


    grd.DataSource = table;
    grd.DataBind();
```

**Explanation**

```
    adapter.Fill(ds, "ABC");
```

here ABC is a temp name of table you can take anything.

```
table = ds.Tables["ABC"];
```

and write here same table name as you have taken a temp table name.
now try it.

Comment: That only changed the syntax. It didn't solve my problem at all